# Save values separated by new line and separated by space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to save values from textbox. Like this:

1. 777 888
   111 222

and then the values has to be saved like this:

```
<ipaddresses>
    <ipaddress>777</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>888</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>111</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>222</ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
```

but now I get this as output:

```
<ipaddresses>
    <ipaddress>11</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>22</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>33</ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
<ipaddresses>
    <ipaddress>11</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>22</ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
<ipaddresses>
    <ipaddress>11</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>22</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>33</ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
```

I try it like this:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model)
{
    XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
    XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");

    if (IpAddress == null)
       return string.Empty;                 

    string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine,  }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    lines = IpAddress.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        if (item.StartsWith("127") || item.StartsWith("192"))
            //return  ("LogOnDetails", model);
            return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

                    IPAddress address;// = null;
                    if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
                    {

                        switch (address.AddressFamily)
                        {
                            case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                                ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                                // we have IPv4
                                break;
                            case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                                // we have IPv6
                                ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    settings.Add(ipaddresses);
                }

            return settings.ToString();
        }
```

Thank you. If somebody has any suggestion. Thank you

The problem is then If I do this:

1. 11 99 22 33
2. 88
3. 99

then only this values: 11 99 22 will be saved

and if I do this:

1. 1 2 3
2. 4 5

then only the numbers:

```
<ipaddress>1</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>2</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>5</ipaddress>
```

will be saved

and this was doing the trick:

```
  lines = IpAddress.Split(new char[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this line

`settings.Add(ipaddresses);`

to outside the `for` loop. e.g.

```
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    //... Rest of loop code.
}

settings.Add(ipaddresses);
```

The XML should then look like this:

```
<settings>
  <ipaddresses>
    <ipaddress>11</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>22</ipaddress>
    <ipaddress>33</ipaddress>
  </ipaddresses>
</settings>
```